# field of fractions of $k[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ be a field and suppose $$k(X)=\text{field of fractions of }\ k[X]=\left\{ \frac{f(X)}{g(X)}\mid f,g\in k[X], g\neq 0\right\}.$$

> Show that $k(X)$ is not a finitely generated $k$-algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\;k(X)=k\left[ \frac{f_i(X)}{g_i(X)}\;,\;\;1\le i\le n\right]\;$ , then there is a finite number of prime elements that can appear as factors of the the denominator of any element generated as a polynomial in the above $\;n\;$ elements and coefficients in $\;k\;$ .

It is enough then to show there is an infinite number of prime elements in $\;k[X]\;$, following the directions of Euclid's demonstration of the infinitude of primes in $\;\Bbb N\;$